# how to execute ng build for nested ng2 app where node_modules is in parent dir?

Tags: angular

I have an ng4 app which is nested in a parent .NET MVC app.  node_modules exists in the parent MVC app. When I exec ng build cmd on the nested ng4 app, I get an ENOENT error indicating that ng build did not find node_modules as a subdir within my nested ng4 app. Is there any config change I can make so the build process looks for node_modules in the app's parent dir?

Or, in order to run CLI for this scenario, will I be required to take a hackier approach where I maintain an additional copy of the node_modules dir within the ng4 subdir?

**UPDATE**

Looks like this particular issue has been discussed in another thread:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3864

"move the angular-cli.json in the same dir as node_modules and change the root path in the angular-cli.json"

I'm guessing that this workaround should work for me. But another dev posted the following url to the bottom of the same thread:

"fix(@angular/cli): use require for @angular/core check #7601"
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/7601

The github status for this fix says that the commit was merged into master 13 days ago.  I installed CLI only a few days ago so this update should be included in the version of the CLI that I installed. Do I need to reinstall one or more of the ng2 libs or am I missing some other step here?